# NGINX: 504 Gateway Time-out

Tags: nginx, timeout, gateway

```
events {
 worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
include       mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;


sendfile        on;

keepalive_timeout  65;



server {
    listen  0.0.0.0:9001;
    server_name  localhost;




    location / {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:9000; 
    }
}
}
```

I am running NGINX on Windows 7. I have Grunt server up and running on 9000 port on my localhost. I receive "504 Gateway Time-out" each time I try to load localhost:9001.

Do I need to add something to run it on windows ? Is there anything to do with the firewall?

Please suggest solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Address 0.0.0.0 is not the same as localhost. Change the address to 127.0.0.1 will fix the problem.

Also see http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0

> In the Internet Protocol version 4 the address 0.0.0.0 is a non-routable meta-address used to designate an invalid, unknown or non applicable target. To give a special meaning to an otherwise invalid piece of data is an application of in-band signaling.